# How can I convert a complete bootstrap template into a WordPress template?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, theme-customizer

I have download a bootstrap css template, how can I use a complete bootstrap template as a WordPress template?

Comment: THis is not the correct place to ask this.. please find out some online tutorials and after that if you are stuck post the question stating where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert all the files to basic php files as WordPress supports.WordPress basic files are index.php,header.php,footer.php,category.php,page.php,single.php and stylesheet file name as style.css with some info about your theme like theme name,theme url etc

Comment: May i know complete guide,

Comment: Yes you can ask what you want

Comment: How can i import sample data of wordpress theme

Comment: Many of the premium themes have option in their theme options page for import its demo content. You can use any theme like DIVI theme, Avada theme etc